# how to bind `ws` message event twice and unbind the first one

Tags: node.js

I use `ws` for node websocket client.

I need to bind on the client stream twice, and later, unbind the first stream.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer(
{
  port: 9998
});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) //for every DLL websocket
 { 
    var wsTL = function(tl)
    { 
      ws.on('message', function(msg)
      {
         cosole.log(msg);
      }
    }

     wsTL();
     wsTL(); // ws.on('message',..) is binded again

     ws.off('message');  // I want to unbind the first event. 
      // but actually, there's no 'off' , so error here
  }
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Just looking through the source, the method may be called `removeListener()`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried just after my question. For unknown reason, it did not work. Now I try another approach and quit trying to unbind. ..